# Test for JPA @Query method fails, but method works in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-test

I want to test `enableUser(String email)`, which is a @Query method in my `UserRepository`. The method simply sets `enabled` field to `TRUE`. Below is the code for the method:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    ...

    User getByEmail(String email);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User a " +
            "SET a.enabled = TRUE " +
            "WHERE a.email = ?1")
    void enableUser(String email);
}
```

This is the `User` entity class. The field `enabled` is set to `false` by default unless stated otherwise in the `@AllArgsConstructor`:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Integer id;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;
    private boolean locked = false;
    private boolean enabled = false;

    public User(String fullName, String email, String password, UserRole role) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    ...    

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }
}
```

This is the test that is failing. First, I am creating a new instance of `User` and saving in into the database. Then I try to enable the user, retrieve him by email and check whether `isEnabled()` returns `true`. However, it does not:

```
@DataJpaTest
class UserRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository componentUnderTest;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Ensure the query for enabling a user works.")
    void enableUser() {
        User user = new User("full name", "test@mail.com", "passwd", UserRole.USER);
        componentUnderTest.save(user);
        componentUnderTest.enableUser("test@mail.com");
        User enabledUser = componentUnderTest.getByEmail("test@mail.com");
        assertThat(enabledUser.isEnabled()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

I have set `spring.jpa.show-sql` to `true` and this is the output. The queries run successfully:

```
Hibernate: call next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: insert into user (email, enabled, full_name, locked, password, role, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update user set enabled=1 where email=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.email as email2_2_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_2_, user0_.full_name as full_nam4_2_, user0_.locked as locked5_2_, user0_.password as password6_2_, user0_.role as role7_2_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?
```

The database I am using for testing is H2, but the test fails on MySQL as well. I should also mention that **the method works in production**, so I believe it has something to do with the test.

**EDIT**:
Here is the stacktrace:
https://pastebin.com/mjXeLBzE

Comment: What error you are getting during fail of test case? Your stacktrace. And what is there in getByEmail method?

Comment: @GauravJeswani I have added a pastebin of the stacktrace on the bottom. The ```getByEmail``` method returns a ```User``` object. JPA picks up the name of the method and creates the query by itself.

Comment: Why do you use a modifiying query instead of updating the user entity? The update bypasses the persistence context and then you get the old user from the context and not the updated one